# SpringDataJPAを使ったDB関連の設定を、異なる設定方法で共有する方法

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Maven, Spring4, SpringDataJPAを使ったWEBアプリケーションを作成しており、
おおまかですが、下記のような構成になっています。

spring-webプロジェクト

web.xm

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

spring-context.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:spring-datasource.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="{package}"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/WEB-INF/img/" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

database.properties

```
hibernate.generate_statistics = true
hibernate.show_sql = true

jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://host:3306/db
jdbc.username=user
jdbc.password=user
```

spring-serviceプロジェクト

spring-datasource.xml

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="${package}"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<!-- jpa -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

この後、バッチプロジェクトにて
DBの基本構造(spring-datasource.xmlまで)を共有したいのですが、
spring-webプロジェクトでは設定ファイルがweb.xml始動であり、
今後共通化するspring-batch(現状DB接続していない)プロジェクトでは、
実行クラスから設定クラスを呼び出す形になっています。

main.java

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringBatchConfig.class);
ExecClass o = ctx.getBean(ExecClass.class);
o.execute();
```

この場合、双方で設定方法が異なると、共通(spring-serviceプロジェクトのspring-context.xmlからspring-datasource.xmlまで)の設定を読み込むことはできないのでしょうか？